# Something is wrong with my PDO query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Okay, so here is a troublesome chunk of a small PHP script I'm trying to write:

```
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $pdusername = $_POST['username'];
    $pdpassword = $_POST['password'];
    $pdemail = $_POST['email'];
    $crumbs = '
        {"qActive":"","cardColor":8,"storage":"F0004a,F206","closet":"P001,C301c,C415a,C601a,C010a,C303a,C744,BG037,BG101,C401c,GI704,C456b","memberOnly":"","qItems":"","color":"1","coins":1000,"allowFriends":1,"email":"'.$pdemail.'","isEligible":"1","bankCount":"","isEmailValidated":1,"isMember":1,"lastGame":"MG001","isZing":1,"xp":0,"qCount":0,"bank":"","isSafe":"0","gold":0,"bday":"1/1/2000,382","festivalCollection":0,"wearing":"","tickets":0,"xpLevel":0,"lastPlayed":"1/1/2015,383","games":"MG001,MG002,MG003","isMod":0,"mounts":"","backpack":"","level":"1"}
    ';
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO users (username,nickname,email,password,active,parent,ubdate,level,memberexpiry,crumbs,ismod)
    VALUES ("'.$pdusername.'","","'.$pdemail.'","'.$pdpassword.'",1,0,"",1,-1,"'.$crumbs.'",0)';
    $db->query($sql);
}
```

However, when I submit the form, I get this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'qActive":"","cardColor":8,"storage":"F0004a,F206","closet":"P001,C301c,C415a,C60' at line 2' in /var/www/html/register/index.php:35 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/register/index.php(35): PDO->query('INSERT INTO use...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/register/ind
```

Why would that be? :/

Comment: Echo `$sql` what does it give you? You are also open to SQL injections with this code.

Comment: It would be better the use of prepared statement: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: You wrap `$crumbs` in double quotes - `"'.$crumbs.'"`, but since `$crumbs` contains double quotes - `$crumbs = '{"qActive":""...` it will break syntax. You need to escape your quotes. Or even better use prepared statements/parameters.

Comment: @chris85> that's exactly what's happening, by the way. The `$crumbs` variable is dumped into the query, and the SQL parser chokes on the first quote it finds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with how you build your sql query esp. around the $crumbs part - it's not marked as a string literal for MySQL.
Your script is also prone to [sql injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).
You could use [prepared statements](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to get rid of those problems.

```
<?php

if ( isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']) ) {
    // <-- maybe some other sanity check here? -->
    $stmt = $db->prepare("
        INSERT INTO
            users
            (username,nickname,email,password,active,parent,ubdate,level,memberexpiry,crumbs,ismod)
        VALUES
            (:username,'',:email,:password, 1, 0, '', 1, -1,:crumbs, 0)
    ");

    $stmt->execute( array(
        'username'=> $_POST['username'],
        'email'   => $_POST['email'],
        'password'=> $_POST['password'],
        'crumbs'  => '{"qActive":"","cardColor":8,"storage":"F0004a,F206","closet":"P001,C301c,C415a,C601a,C010a,C303a,C744,BG037,BG101,C401c,GI704,C456b","memberOnly":"","qItems":"","color":"1","coins":1000,"allowFriends":1,"email":"'.$pdemail.'","isEligible":"1","bankCount":"","isEmailValidated":1,"isMember":1,"lastGame":"MG001","isZing":1,"xp":0,"qCount":0,"bank":"","isSafe":"0","gold":0,"bday":"1/1/2000,382","festivalCollection":0,"wearing":"","tickets":0,"xpLevel":0,"lastPlayed":"1/1/2015,383","games":"MG001,MG002,MG003","isMod":0,"mounts":"","backpack":"","level":"1"}'
    ) );

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick.

I am fully aware of how to prevent SQL injections and how to implement other form validation methods, but it's the PDO I was struggling with, so I just threw it in here hoping to get some help. Thanks again!